# JS create an array with objects from other array

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

```
let array1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
let array2 = [6,7,8,9,10]
let array3 = [ {x: array1, y: array2} ]
```

How to write correctly loop, so in output I will get 1 array with 5 ojects inside?

//Expected output

```
[ {x: 1, y: 6}, {x: 2, y: 7}, {x: 3, y: 8}, {x: 4, y: 9}, {x: 5, y: 10}]
```

Comment: It should be obvious that you need a loop.

Comment: Can you maybe suggest the way you would loop through it? The variable array3 may bring some confusion.

Answer (score 1):

You should loop through all the values of the first array with `.map` which generates a new array. The function inside of `.map` takes the value from array1 as `value` and array2 as `array2[index]`;

```
let array1 = [1,2,3,4,5]
let array2 = [6,7,8,9,10]
let array3 = array1.map(function (value, index) {
    return {x: value, y: array2[index]}
})
console.log(array3);
```

I've intentionally used slightly more verbose solution that could be required for easier readability and understanding.